# I am using py2exe tool generate exe and I am using openpyxl library. Getting Import error

Tags: python, executable, py2exe, openpyxl

I am using `py2exe` tool to generate exe and I am using openpyxl library. 
Getting Import error.

```

```
  from distutils.core import setup 
   import py2exe 

   setup( 
       console=["Vector.py"], 
       options = { 
        "py2exe":{ 
              "includes":["openpyxl"] 
              }
          } 
       )
```

```

****Error:****

```
C:\Users\t7245mh\Desktop\Vector\Script\New files>python Setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    "includes":["openpyxl"]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1297, in find_n
eeded_modules
    mf.import_hook(mod)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_pack
age
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named openpyxl
```

Comment: Can you tell us any more details about the error? Also, your formatting may be a concern.  Please edit your code to use a code block (triple backticks before and after the code) so we can see if there are problems in that regard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and response                                          Getting below Error:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_pack
age
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named openpyxl

Comment: Could you move what you posted as a comment to the body of your question somewhere?  It is tough to read exactly what you wrote in a comment format.

Comment: Added Error in question, Please have look.

Comment: As silly of a question as this is, can you verify that `openpyxl` is in the directory that the import module is looking for it in?

Comment: openpyxl is present in                                                             C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\openpyxl-2.1.5-py2.7.egg\openpyxl

Comment: Take a look at this page, which I believe may answer your question: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs

Comment: If it solves your problem, be sure to answer your own question with a thorough explanation of what was going wrong and how you fixed it. Otherwise future visitors will be left wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem:

I had the `openpyxl` package installed with the .egg zip format which was unrecognized by `py2exe`.

Solution:

I used the link [py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/ExeWithEggs) 
and re-installed open openpyxl by using the command below:

`easy_install --always-unzip \\Python_Libraries\openpyxl-1.8.6\`

Comment: Feel free to select your own answer as "accepted" as well.

Comment: How do you undo the "always unzip" I don't want it to unzip it everytime.